# How to compute the derivative of $\frac{\partial\mathbf{a}_k }{\partial{X}_{ij}}$ when $X = A^TB$

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Assume I have

$$ X = A^TB $$

where $X \in R^{m \times n}, A \in R^{r \times m}, A \in R^{r \times n}$.

Let's define $A = [\mathbf{a}_1, ..., \mathbf{a}_m]$ where $\mathbf{a}_k $ is the $k$-th column of matrix $A$. How to compute the following derivative?

$$\frac{\partial\mathbf{a}_k }{\partial{X}_{ij}}$$

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\partial a_k}{\partial X_{ij}}$?

Comment: yes, here $\mathbf{a}_k$ is a vector, I lose the partial. thanks

Comment: You seem to be confused about the dimensions of $A$.

Comment: really? In the homework, the $A \in R^{r \times m}$ there is a transpose in the equation. Let me know if the problem itself has problem. I will let my lecturer know. Thanks.

Comment: Read your question carefully. You introduce the dimensions of $A$ twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$\eqalign{
C^T &= B^+ \quad &({\rm pseudoinverse\,of\,} B) \cr
{\mathcal H}_{ijkl} &= \delta_{il}\delta_{jk} \quad &({\rm isotropic\,tensor}) \cr
X_{ji} &= {\mathcal H}_{ijkl}X_{kl} \quad &({\rm index\,notation}) \cr
X^T &= {\mathcal H}:X \quad &({\rm matrix\,notation}) \cr
}$$
Your question assumes that $A$ can be expressed as a function of $X$, so let's do that.

Then we'll calculate the differential and the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
A &= CX^T = C{\mathcal H}:X \cr
dA &= C{\mathcal H}:dX \cr
\frac{\partial A}{\partial X} &= C{\mathcal H} \cr
\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial X_{pq}}
 &= C_{ik}{\mathcal H}_{kjpq} = B^+_{ki}\delta_{kq}\delta_{jp} = B^+_{qi}\delta_{jp}   \cr
}$$
The result is a fourth-order tensor, and these are its component. To express it in terms of the columns of $A$ and $C$, sum over the $i$-index with vectors from the standard basis.
$$\eqalign{
{\mathbf a}_j &= A_{ij}\,{\mathbf e}_i \cr
{\mathbf c}_q &= C_{iq}\,{\mathbf e}_i = B^+_{qi}\,{\mathbf e}_i \cr
\frac{\partial {\mathbf a}_{j}}{\partial X_{pq}}
 &= B^+_{qi}\delta_{jp} {\mathbf e}_i = \delta_{jp}\,{\mathbf c}_q \cr
}$$

Comment: The final section of the answer originally expressed the gradient of the _rows_ of $A$. Now it's been updated to produce a gradient for the _columns_ of $A$.